# Getting answer from node server in a jQuery get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I perform a get call to server (**node.js** in this case) sending a JSON (args) to a cetain route. However I can't receive anything from server. I'd like to get back another JSON.

This is my call:

```
$.get("/taylor",args,function(resultado){
    console.log(resultado.data)
},"json")
```

This is how I catch it at server side:

```
server.get("/taylor",function(peticion,respuesta){
    console.log(peticion.query)
    respuesta.send(anyJSON)
})
```

I get the JSON at node server side but the sentence `console.log(resultado.data)` at client side prints anything :/

Comment: is this console.log(peticion.query) statement printing anything?

Comment: Yes, it does. I get the JSON printed

Comment: are you using express.js?

Comment: resultado? respuesta? What is it, the 90s ;-) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express.js you can send it by

```
respuesta.json({anyJson:"anyJson"});
```

If you want to send data to the server then try this.
Please note that if you follow this method you should accept the reqObject as RequestParam and not RequestBody. This is one way to do it. There might be another better way.

```
getData("get",reqObject,"/api/abc/url/",myFunction);
//reqObject is the json object which you want to send to server.
function getData(type,reqObject,url,callBack)  {
        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            data: reqObject ,
            dataType: "json",
            url: url ,
            success: function(response){
               callBack(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

You may have to take care of this pointer.

Comment: Great, am I OK about giving "json" as parameter to the get function?

Comment: didnt get you. Please explain

Comment: When I do `$.get` I give "json" as last parameter, is that ok?

Comment: Do you want to send some data to the server in your get request?

Comment: Yeah, I send args, which happened to be a JSON

Comment: @diegoaguilar I have edited the answer. Please check

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question: what about callback argument in `getData` function. What would it be an example of defining it

Comment: callBack is any function in your js. in my example it is myFunction. It should be any predefined function. This function will be called when the request is successful